# Correct path on Windows for custom beamer style files

Tags: beamer, miktex, paths

I've recently switched to windows from linux and I'm having trouble getting my custom beamer style files to compile correctly.  I have them in `~/texmf/tex/latex/local` currently.  There are other style files in there that are working correctly so the directory is on the right tex path, and when I copy the style files into the same directory as the code they also work.

Does beamer use a different path ?  I ran `texhash.exe`, is there a separate command to set the beamer path?

Comment: Are you using TeX Live or MikTeX? In general, Windows don't have the flexibility of maintaining your own distro so better don't touch anything. Rather use the package install wizards (oxymoron).

Comment: Well for TeXLive all the beamer style files are in `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\tex\latex`, but they should be found in the folder you created, so this is strange. You could try to put it in the explicit beamer folder in the above directory. Here: `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\tex\latex\beamer\themes\theme`

Comment: I'm using MikTeX 2.9. The beamer files are in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\*` and they all seem to be loading fine, just not my custom files.

Comment: You should not modify your MikTeX folder. Put your custom style files either in the working directory or somewhere TeX can find them.

Comment: ...somewhere TeX can find them: [Which is the best directory to keep .sty files where MiKTeX can find them?](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/faq.html#styfiles) for eg: `C:\localtexfiles\tex\latex\misc\custombeamer.sty` and Refresh FNDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad.  It turns out that texpath.exe wasn't updating the path correctly.  For anyone that wants to fix this, after adding files to your ~/texmf/tex/latex/local directory (or whatever you're using) you need to refresh the MikTeX path.   Go to *MiKTeX 2.X > Maintenance (Admin) > Settings (Admin)* (or without the (Admin), if that is not in your menus)*, "General" tab > "Refresh FNDB"*.

I got the answer from [this site](http://www.matdat.life.ku.dk/LaTeX/Frederiksberg/install.html)